# How to Setup VPN server in Windows Server 2008 on Amazon Cloud E2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn

I have servers in Amazon Cloud E2 with Windows Server 2008 R2. I want to setup a VPN server.  Can any one guide me?  Because as per the MS articles I completed the steps but I am not able to connect the VPN.

Any can share or guide me, how to setup a VPN in Windows Server on EC2.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the articles you're following, and tell us where you're stuck?

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for your update. this is link i followed http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKdE5p0MVl0. if possible please provide the step or link for EC2 windows vpn. Thanks

Comment: did you mean EC2?

Answer (score 1):

That particular tutorial will not work (PPTP traffic will never reach EC2 instance) but there are ways (I have one running flawlessly for months, on AWS VPC) : [How to configure an L2TP/IPsec server behind a NAT-T device in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926179)

Comment: after changing the setting, it will work ?

Comment: I have no way to tell if you set up everything correctly....

Comment: I have changed the setting, But still i am notable to connect VPN. if possible pls share link or steps for How to setup a VPN in amazon cloud EC2 .

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the security group firewall has the correct ports open.

Comment: What ports has to be open in EC2 Firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add port 1723 and the GRE protocol to the Incoming section of the security group associated with server.